# How list the owners of collections in mongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

How to list the MongoDB collections and the owners of the collections.
How is it possible?

Like we have in Postgresql by using the  \dt command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `show dbs` to see the list of the databases available to you and then use `use dbname` after that use `show collections` or `db.getCollectionNames()` to see all the collections in that database.

Comment: I want the collection together with owner of the collection. How to list like that?

Comment: when you use a collection you switch to a database then you use it so you should be knowing the database, but still if you get the name of the databse just write "db.collectionName" it will give you "databasename.collectionName".